# Query to Kinvey with regex

Tags: regex, variables, kinvey

I have tried to make a query to Kinvey database with regex.

I want query with variable and before and after the variable it's possible to have random text.

This is my query:

```
if (searchedWord) {
    query = `?query={"title":"${searchedWord}"}`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check following example to understand how to use regex while forming a query:

?query={"firstName":{"$regex":"^Jo" }}  -- Would match John and Joe

If above example doesn't help, please elaborate your usecase.

Thanks,
Pranav
Kinvey